# How would i parseInt this

Tags: java

i have tried like this

```
public Set<String> getEvens() {
    Set<String> evens = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (String a : list) {
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
            evens.add(x);
        }
    }
}
```

and this

```
public Set<String> getEvens() {
    Set<String> evens = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (String a : list) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            evens.add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

but neither work and I'm not sure what else to try. I haven't used `parseInt` in a while and might be doing it wrong also

These are the errors I get:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '%'
error: no suitable method found for add(int)
```

Comment: add the error you are getting

Comment: @Prateek the first boils down to "can't mod a string" and the second is "undefined variable `a`".

Comment: First, you should indent your code properly.

Comment: @Kevin I knew that but wanted him to know that. We can point out his mistake once not always. Its better if he can pinpoint this on his own in the future

Comment: if (a%2==0) I believe a is a String.. I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second will almost work, it's just your `parseInt` is not within the `for`'s curly braces, you will also need to use `%` on `x` (the `int`), not `a` (the `String`).

```
public Set<String> getEvens()
{
    Set<String> evens = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (String a : list)
    {
        int x =Integer.parseInt(a);
        if (x % 2==0)
        {
            evens.add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is right, except use x%2 instead of a%2

Answer (score 0):

Operator `%` works only on numeric types in Java. Modify your second solution like this:

```
if (x % 2 == 0) {
    evens.add(a);
}
```

There is `x` instead of `a` in the if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Set<String> getEvens(List<String> list) {
    Set<String> evens = new TreeSet<String>();
    // modify for(String a:list){
    for (String a : list) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
        {
            //modify if (a % 2 == 0) {
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                evens.add(a);
            }
        }
    }
    // modify add this }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both examples have a different error, but they are unrelated to parsing int.

```
Example 1: events.add(x), events takes Strings while x is int.
Example 2. a%2 is wrong, a is String.
```

Learning how to read stacktraces is fundamental in Java and would easily have helped you here:
[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)